# Limesurvey notification emails will not send

Tags: phpmailer, limesurvey

I've recently noticed an issue with my Limesurvey installation. Until recently, I had a number of surveys set to email the user after submission (using {email} in the "Send detailed admin notification email" box to refer to an email question in the survey). However despite not manually changing anything, they no longer send. Some others do send from within limesurvey, for example from the "Create new admin" option, while token related emails will not.

In the case of token invitations, the debugging there will say emails sent when using php, but the test emails never arrive (multiple emails tested). When using SMTP, I get the below:

> SMTP connect() failed... Some emails were not sent because the server did not accept the email(s) or some other error occured.

I should note that while I first noticed this in existing surveys in version 2.73.0, I've since done a fresh install of 3.1 and created a test survey. So this is pointing at a server config issue, but I haven't had any issues with emails sending except in this specific case.

Any suggestions of particular places to look would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to turn up your debug output - there's not enough info here to know what's causing this.

Comment: @Synchro I've got debugging on and the output above is the most I can get.

Comment: dear Lou -- thx for raising this question - i love to hear from you what happened - and how you did come along with the emails? Does it work now - how did you fix it !?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to change the email method in settings (https://manual.limesurvey.org/Global_settings/en#Email_settings)?

> Email method: This determines how emails are being sent. The following options are available:

```
PHP (default value): uses internal PHP mail function
Sendmail : uses sendmail mailer
SMTP : based on SMTP relaying. Use this setting when you are running LimeSurvey on a host that is not your mail server
    Make sure that you are using your SMTP configured email (Global settings -> Email settings) if you use SMTP, otherwise there might be a chance that the following error is displayed: 'SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 553 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: not owned by user'
Qmail : Set this if you are running the Qmail mailer
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)